# Need some SQL advice with selecting max or Top 1 Record

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, crystal-reports

I'm trying to edit a Crystal Reports SQL Expression where the original designer used the following SQL Expression to pull notes from a drive:

```
(select max(Text) from rpt_NotesDetail 
 where DriveID="DriveMaster"."DriveID" and
        Reason in (select codeid 
                   from rpt_QuickCodes 
                   where DescShort like N'Publicity'))
```

We don't want it to pull max(Text), we are looking for it to grab the latest (or most recent) note in the NotesDetail table based on the createdate field.

I have tried two ways to handle this and I'm getting an error on both:

```
(select (Text) from rpt_NotesDetail 
 where DriveID="DriveMaster"."DriveID"
 and createdate = (select max(createdate) 
                   from rpt_notesdetail 
                   where DriveID="DriveMaster"."DriveID")
                   and Reason in (select codeid 
                                  from rpt_QuickCodes 
                                  where DescShort like N'Publicity'))


(select (Text) 
 from rpt_NotesDetail 
  where DriveID="DriveMaster"."DriveID"
    and createdate = (select top 1 createdate 
                      from rpt_notesdetail 
                      where DriveID="DriveMaster"."DriveID" 
                      order by "drivemaster"."fromdatetime" desc)
    and Reason in (select codeid 
                   from rpt_QuickCodes 
                   where DescShort like N'Publicity'))
```

Both expressions are giving me this error:
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <=, >, >=, or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Not sure what would be the cause of this error, any suggestions?

Comment: "the cause of this error" is clearly stated: "Subquery returned more than 1 value."

Comment: You have more than one row with the same maximum createdate for the same DriveID.

Comment: what is the code preceding either of those queries, are you populating a variable?

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize until this post that the create date field is only receiving the date on the time stamp, not the time as well. There is also a NoteID column in this table, I think that should be used to resolve the time stamp conflict.